# What are the web3py equivalent for communicating with bitcoin in Python?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, python

I am fairly new to working with Python, I have a requirement where I need to perform some basic bitcoin operations on my local system rather than relying on some external API's, those function mainly include :

**1. Wallet Creation**

**2. Address Creation**

**3. Transaction signing**

For other operations, I am willing to use external API's like blockcypher. I need the above operations to be performed locally so to ensure some security. FOr ethereum I use web3.py which provides me these functions.
Can anyone help me with the same for bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [API reference (JSON-RPC)](http://laanwj.github.io/bitcoin-python/doc/introduction.html) (which has a python example, but might be out of date) and available [Bitcoin Core apis](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bitcoin-core-apis).

Here is a nice [clickable version of docs for bitcoin-python](http://laanwj.github.io/bitcoin-python/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like Web3py or Web3js are connected to a node using JSON-RPC behind the scene. I am not aware of any library for bitcoin like Web3py. But Bitcoin do provide JSON-RPC interface, which you can use to perform these operations.